# Windows printer driver returns "GetInfo() exit pcbNeeded is NULL" error

Tags: c++, winapi, driver, printers

I am using [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/print/OEM%20Printer%20Customization%20Plug-in%20Samples/C%2B%2B/oemps) example to create a printer driver for windows 10. It is returning the error

```
IOemPS::GetInfo() exit pcbNeeded is NULL!
```

when we give the print from Windows 10 photos (default image viewer for windows 10).
But the above driver is working from all other applications like MS-paint, windows photo viewer, pdf viewer etc.

I don't understand why it is giving error while printing image from Photos application.

Comment: What is unclear about the error? The `IOemPS::GetInfo()` method is being called with its `pcbNeeded` parameter set to `NULL`, but the method requires it to point at a valid `DWORD` variable instead (see the implementation in `intrface.cpp`). The official [`IPrintOemPS::GetInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/prcomoem/nf-prcomoem-iprintoemps-getinfo) documentation does not say the `pcbNeeded` parameter can be `NULL`. So this is clearly a bug in whatever caller is requesting info from the driver